# Securing database information inside Java application

Tags: java, mysql, security

I've recently gone into a serious security problem in my Java app. The client application simply works on a FTP and MySQL server, and access information to both of them are stored directly in code. I'm aware that it's an awfull idea and I'm planning to move that informations to a preferences file. But how can it help to raise a security level on my app? Is there any way to properly secure such file? Or should I look for a different solution?

Comment: This is a near duplicate of many of the "related questions" -- start with those, then see if you have a more specific question.

Comment: Well, from what I've discovered, it all came down to the three-tier-model. I have got no idea how to implement that into a typical java application. I feel it's a little bit to much so that's why I ask about easier but also secure solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep passwords in a keystore (example: http://kingsfleet.blogspot.com/2008/12/storing-password-somewhere-safe.html). Keystore has to be protected with a password, so in order to use client application user needs to give keystore password - I am not sure if this is acceptable in your case.

Comment: Well, those informations could be hold in a keystore, but the password to that should be generated on the "first run" for each user to decrease the number of password to just one. What about this approach?

Comment: Yes, you need some method to create keystore and keystore password, it can be done during creation of installer for each client application or, as you've proposed, during first application run.

Comment: I've just realized that this solution is not going to work as expected. Each user having own password to given keystore can easily use this password to retrieve database host/username/pass.

Comment: In that case you need some serverside component. User needs to login to application, application would connect securely with FTP or MySQL server using passwords that user would never see.